# JavaHL isn't working

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I try to update a project from SVN (I have a fresh install of eclipse but it's an existing workspace) so I installed subclipse but when I want to to do anything with SVN I get error messages like :

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

or

```
Problems reported while synchronizing SVNStatusSubscriber. 0 of 1 resources were synchronized.
An error occurred synchronizing <Project name>: Error getting status for resource P<Project name> Unable to load default SVN Client
Error getting status for resource P<Project name> Unable to load default SVN Client
Unable to load default SVN Client
```

I work on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with eclipse indigo 3.7.2.

Can someone help me to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is detailed in this Wiki page:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

You need to install Subversion native libraries including the JavaHL library.  I would recommend using MacPorts or HomeBrew to get the native libraries.

Comment: The most important part of http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL is probably http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de (Get the right version). You must ensure that the Subclipse version installed matches the native library version, especially when using MacPorts (or HomeBrew) where you usually do a "sudo port update outdated". Done so, you have very likely a newer version of JavaHL' native libs installed than allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Does one really need to have JavaHL? I was just ignoring the error and I could still use svn without any problem.

Comment: JavaHL is usually the default Subversion client, please check Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN interface. If JavaHL is not available, SVNKit (if available) is tried. That one works usually out of the box due to its 100% Java nature.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your version of Subclipse and your native JavaHL libraries match (please check http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL for details).

When unsure about the version of JavaHL, do something like

```
$ strings /opt/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.a | fgrep svn:
svn:auth:username
svn:auth:password
svn:auth:config-dir
svn: 
svn:1.8.8 (r1568071)
```

Here, I have the 1.8.8 version installed. Btw, this one appears to work well with Subclipse 1.10.x.

Then check whether your native library folder, for example /opt/local/lib when using MacPorts, is taken into account. MacPorts for example adds symbolic link /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl.jnilib, thus there is no need to configure java.library.path on launching Eclipse or STS.

Again if unsure, you may try something like

```
STS --launcher.appendVmargs -vmargs -Djava.library.path=/opt/local/lib
```

Be aware however, that the launch configuration above overrides the default setting of java.library.path which may trigger other (non 100% pure) plugins to fail.